# context menu on QTableView and qt 5.6 breaking changes under windows 7?

Tags: c++, qt

It seems there is a breaking change on Qt 5.6 and under windows 7 (I don't have the problem under windows 10):

Under Qt 5.4/windows7 with the following code I had no problem:

// .h

```
class XXX: public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QMenu *menu_;
    void init();

private Q_SLOTS:    
    void showOrderDlg(const QModelIndex & index); 
    void ActionGridContextMenu(QAction* action);
};
```

// .cpp

```
void XXX::init(QPoint)
{
    setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(showContextMenu(QPoint)));
    menu_ = new QMenu(this);    
    (menu_->addAction("Start"))->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Resources/Image/1.png"));
    (menu_->addAction("Stop"))->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/Resources/Image/2.png"));
    connect(menu_, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)),this, SLOT(ActionGridContextMenu(QAction*)));
}

void XXX::showContextMenu(QPoint)
{ 
    menu_->exec(QCursor::pos()); 
}

void XXX::ActionGridContextMenu(QAction* action)
{

}
```

I have updated to Qt 5.6, and no menu is shown now...

**It seems class which not derivated from `QTableView` are not impacted**.

Is there a thing I do wrong here ?

EDIT: see my last comment for the fix

Comment: There appears to be  a fair bit of relevant code missing.  You initialize `menu` but in your `showContextMenu` override you call `exec` against `contextmenuTree`.  Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @G.M.done with comment on QTableView

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce.  I've taken your code as an example, built it against Qt5.6.1 and all appears ok.  The only change I made was to use the new `connect` syntax that takes explicit function pointers rather than using the `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` macros.

Comment: @G.m: by moving`connect(menu_, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)),this, SLOT(ActionGridContextMenu(QAction*)));` into `showContextMenu` this works